# Following error raised: TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain) django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-errors

I am trying to handle errors in my Django project and I keep receiving the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 132, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 184, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request)
  File "/Users/Tom/Desktop/squeasy /tasks/views.py", line 31, in handler500
    response = render(request, template_name)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/Tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/squeasy_-djXBooHN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

For my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR /'squeasy/tasks/templates/tasks'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have also tried:

```
'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

and

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

and

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
```

I have no other errors when running templates normally, it is only when I force an error.

I have the following **views.py** to handle 400, 403 and 404 error requests:

```
def handler400(request, exception, template_name = "400.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 400
    return response

def handler403(request, exception, template_name = "403.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response

def handler404(request, exception, template_name="404.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

def handler500(request, template_name="500.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

In my Project's **urls.py** file I have:

```
    handler400 = 'tasks.views.handler400'
    handler403 = 'tasks.views.handler403'
    handler404 = 'tasks.views.handler404'
    handler500 = 'tasks.views.handler500'
```

The app that the views are in is named tasks.

`DEBUG = False` is in my settings.py file.

Comment: In what directory is your `500.html` file located?

Comment: probably you have `500.html` in wrong folder.

Comment: Problem sorted shown below

Answer (score 0):

Answer shown below:

```
def handler400(request, exception, template_name = "tasks/400.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 400
    return response

def handler403(request, exception, template_name = "tasks/403.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response

def handler404(request, exception, template_name="tasks/404.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

def handler500(request, template_name="tasks/500.html"):
    response = render(request, template_name)
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Issue was that I only had `400.html` instead of `tasks/400.html`